# Make a Bike faster

Tags: lubricant

Few months ago I bought this cycle (http://www.gtbicycles.com/usa_en/2014/bikes/mountain/recreational-hardtails/2014-timberline-2-0). Now I would like to make my cycle faster. I would like to know about lubrication. Which lubrication steps can make my bike faster ?? I would like to know more about other steps also which can make my bike faster.

Comment: Why do you think lubrication is the problem?

Comment: Smoother tires, higher tire pressure, and locking out the suspension are about all you can do to improve road speed.  Off-road it's up to you.  Unless the bike was very poorly lubed to begin with, additional lubrication (other than keeping your chain clean and oiled) will have no effect.

Comment: I am not a moderator - this is just one opinion.  You have 3 very general questions and not a single accepted answer.  More specific questions are more effective and don't forget to give a check mark if you do get an answer.

Comment: Whichever way the wind is blowing,  ride in that direction only.   You might wind up out in the "boonies" but your bike will be faster.

Comment: Ride down a hill. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the bike is new then no extra lubrication should be required. According to Sheldon Brown "New chains come pre-lubricated with a grease-type lubricant which has been installed at the factory. This is an excellent lubricant, and ... is superior to any lube that you can apply after the fact.
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/chains.html#factory
If the bike is really old then repacking your wheel hubs can reduce resistance to cycling. This involves cleaning and regreasing the bearing that your wheels run on.

Ultimately, the rider is what makes the bike go the fastest. By improving your core strength and  aerobic capicity you'll be able to ride trails faster for longer.

Answer (score 2):

The major resistance are:

- aerodynamic drag
- tire rolling resistance
  racing tires are going to make the bike faster but they also are expensive and don't last very long
- elevation (gravity)
- mechanical resistance does not even come into play on a properly lubricated bicycle

  - even if there was a magic lube that was twice as slick it would not even be noticeable
  - a lower end bike with lower end bearings will have more resistance but a magic lube is not going to make much difference
  - you have a lower end bike and if you got on a $2000+ bicycle it would be faster but not much different
- shocks absorb some pedal energy
- frame flex will absorb some energy

Answer (score 1):

As far as lubricant in the bottom bracket and the wheel hubs, it depends what grease was used, age of it, and the temperature outside.  I have bikes, with stock grease in the hubs roll really well through all temperatures (-17c to 38) and all ages.  However, I do have a Trek bike for my son (20" MT-60) and when the temperature approached freezing, the wheel hubs and bottom bracket became very stiff and didn't roll well at all.  I was only getting a few turns of the wheel even after vigorous pedaling in my work stand.  I ended up repacking the bearings with the common green stuff in the blue tube and it was a instant improvement.

Repacking only applies though if there is serious drag in them to begin with, and using proven grease.